# Is there a relationship between Entropy of a fininte distrete probability distribution and the squre sum of the values of probability mass function of that distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra

Sorry for the long title. What I mean is that for two vectors (a_1,...,a_n) and (b_1,...,b_n) with the property $a_i,b_i \geq 0 $ and $ \sum a_i =\sum b_i =1$.

If $ -\sum a_ilog(a_i) > -\sum b_ilog(b_i) $ implies  $\sum a_i^2 < \sum b_i^2$ or something similar?

Comment: Certainly not as you ask it. If h(a)>h(b) implied |a|_2<|b|_2,
then h(b)>h(a) would imply |b|_2<|a|_2 and you would get
h(a)>h(b) if and only if |a|_2<|b|_2. 

This would mean that the entropy and the L2 norm are measuring the same thing (they're not).

Comment: @Anthony I am not sure, if it can be ture under this specific condiction.

Comment: and I think for the case n = 2, it is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, in general it is not true that inequality between entropies implies the same inequality between $\ell^2$ norms. Although this is true for $n=2$, it fails already for $n=3$ (as the entropy $H(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is obviously not constant on the level curve determined by conditions $\sum p_i=1$ and $\sum p_i^2=Const$).

Nonetheless, there is a deep link between these two quantities. In order to explain it, it is better  to somewhat change the viewpoint. Namely, given two probability distributions $P=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ and $Q=(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ (for simplicity I assume that all $p_i,q_i$ are strictly positive), the corresponding **Kullback-Leibler deviation** is defined as 
$$
I(Q|P) = \sum p_i \log \frac{p_i}{q_i} \;,
$$
and the so-called **information energy** as
$$
\chi^2(Q,P) = \sum \biggl(\frac{p_i}{q_i}-1\biggr)^2 q_i \;.
$$
Both these quantities measure "closedness" of $P$ and $Q$ (although they are not distances) and are monotone invariants of the pair $(Q,P)$ (they do not increase under quotient maps). If $Q=U_n$ is the uniform distribution, then these quantities are, up to linear rescaling, precisely the entropy and the $\ell^2$-norm of $P$, respectively, as
$$
I(U_n|P) = \log n - H(P)
$$
and
$$
\chi^2(U_n,P) = n \sum p_i^2 - 1 \;.
$$

Now, the link between $I$ and $\chi^2$ is provided by the fact that in naturally defined infinitesimal limits the Kullback-Leibler deviation $I$ and the information energy $\chi^2$ coincide
and produce the **Fisher information metric**. One can read more about this in the corresponding wiki articles, in the old book *Statistical decision rules and optimal inference* by Čencov (AMS, 1982), or in more recent publications on **information geometry**.

Comment: @ R W, first off,  thanks a lot for the very informative reply! But I still have one more question, what do you mean by "naturally defined infinitesimal limits "? do you mean n go to infinite?

Comment: No - infinitesimal here means that time goes to 0. The number of points remains fixed, but instead of a single distribution on $n$ points one looks at a family of distributions parametrized, say, by the interval $[0,1]$ (in other words, about a path in the space of distributions).  